# srun wont stop in sbatch

Tags: linux, bash, cluster-computing, slurm

im trying to run slurm in an specific node in a cluster, the node has two processors, each one of 12 cores, and im trying to run my jobs at the processor level (one task per processor at the same time).

The issue is that when i run it, the processes ran with srun inside my sbatch wont stop slurm output:

```
jobs running: 0

jobs running: 0
[1]+ 12795 Running                 srun --time=00:00:10 --cpu-bind=sockets ./instance_runner.sh satsolver $i &
jobs running: 1
[1]- 12795 Running                 srun --time=00:00:10 --cpu-bind=sockets ./instance_runner.sh satsolver $i &
[2]+ 12845 Running                 srun --time=00:00:10 --cpu-bind=sockets ./instance_runner.sh satsolver $i &
jobs running: 2
processing 0  for satsolver at 16:11:47
processing 0  for satsolver at 16:11:47
```

code

```
# Job name:
#SBATCH --job-name=somename
#
# Account:
#SBATCH --account=myaccount
#
# Partition:
#SBATCH --partition=mypartition
#
# Wall clock limit:
#SBATCH --time=00:45
#
# Specific node
#SBATCH --nodelist=specific node
# Ensure running parallel by processor-level
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
############################################

# Commands to run

function run_instance() {
   echo "processing $1 at $(date, '+%T')"
   sleep 3
}

function run_instances() {
    max_jobs=2
    echo "jobs running: $(jobs -pr | wc -l)"
    for i in {0..2}; do
    echo "$(jobs -l)"
    echo "jobs running: $(jobs -pr | wc -l)"
        srun --time=00:00:10  --cpu-bind=sockets ./instance_runner.sh satsolver $i &
    sleep 1
    done
    wait
}

run_instances $1
```

the process finishes with tiemout because srun never ends the jobs.

the instance_runner.sh is quite simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 3
echo "processing $2  for $1 at $(date '+%T')"
exit 0
```

i had it before with a while that was looking if the srun jobs were finishing:

```
while (( $(jobs -pr | wc -l) >= max_jobs )); do
    echo "max jobs running: $(jobs -pr | wc -l)"
    echo "$(jobs -r)"
    sleep 0.1  # pause to avoid spinning
done
```

and it was constantly printing the maximum jobs running, what could be happening?